# Is euclidian distance an axiomatic concept or is it provable?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

So euclidian distance is defined (in space $R^m$) for points $A(a_1, 1_2,...,a_m)$ and $B(b_1, b_2,...,b_m)$ as $d(A,B)=\sqrt{(a_1-b_1)^2+(a_2-b_2)^2+...+(a_m-b_m)^2}$.

It also can be thought of as the norm of the euclidian space.

Now:

1. If it is axiomatic, then how can it be if Pythagorean theorem, which states basically the same thing, has multiple proofs? But then, if the definition of the distance is fundamental for euclidian geometry, aren't those proofs circular?
2. If it is provable, how do you do that? (without making making circular argument)

*(Or maybe it is axiomatic as a concept but this certain formula isn't?, whatever would mean that...)

I understand that my question may come from the fact that I don't get yet how are the fundamentals of mathematics build. If so, please explain anyway what are the gaps in my reasoning/knowledge.

Comment: Distance is a DEFINITION, not a theorem. In euclidean geometry the distance between points $A$ and $B$ is defined as the length of segment $AB$.

Comment: As already said you define the distance in that way, but i would add that there are proof of the Pythagorean theorem that only uses the [Euclide postulates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclidsPostulates.html), see e.g. [this](https://central.edu/writing-anthology/2019/01/31/159/)

Comment: The formula is derived in two and three dimensions and can be proved. The extension to greater dimensions is based on this and is merely a definition.